# Simplifying this unit normal vector...

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, curvature

I need the unit normal vector to this surface for various computations but I am finding it very hard to work with it:

$$\mathbf{x}(u,v) = r(u) + a(v)\mathbf{n} + b(v)\hat{z}$$

where $r,s$ are unit speed curves on the plane $z=0$, $\hat{z}$ is the unit vector in the z-direction and $s(t) = a(t)\hat{x} + b(t)\hat{y}$. Also $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal to the curve $r$.

What I have is

$$
\mathbf{x_u} = r' + a\mathbf{n}' \quad
\mathbf{x_v} = a'\mathbf{n}+b'\hat{z}
$$

$$N = \frac{\mathbf{x_u}\times \mathbf{x_v}}{|\mathbf{x_u}\times \mathbf{x_v}|}$$

But

$$\mathbf{x_u}\times \mathbf{x_v} = 
(r' \times a'\mathbf{n})+
(r' \times b'\hat{z})+
(a\mathbf{n}'\times a'\mathbf{n})+
(a\mathbf{n}'\times b'\hat{z})
$$

I don't know how to continue from here. How can I simplify this to work with it and get something for $N$

I recognize that $(r' \times a'\mathbf{n})$ is normal to the plane $z=0$ whereas the rest of the terms are on the plane. Not sure how that helps.

In the end my goal is to compute the Gaussian curvature. For that I need the second fundamental form and for that I need some reasonable $N$ to work with.

Otherwise I'm not sure how to compute $\langle N,\mathbf{x_{uu}}\rangle$.

Alternatively is it possible to take the coordinates $\hat{r}, \hat{n},\hat{z}$ so that $\mathbf{x} = (r(u), a(v), b(v))$?

Comment: Should it be $r(t)$ instead of $s(t)$ near the beginning?

Comment: No, there are two unit speed curve on the plane $z=0$. The components of $s(t)$ are part of the space curve $\mathbf{x}$ as indicated. I don't know why it is that way. It's like you have one curve on the plane $z=0$ and then from there you have another curve on the plane made up from $\mathbf{n}$ and $\hat{z}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{t}(u) &= \mathbf{r}' \\
  \mathbf{t}'(u) &= \kappa \mathbf{n} \\
  \mathbf{n}'(u) &= -\kappa \mathbf{t} \\
  \mathbf{t}(u) \times \mathbf{n}(u) &= \mathbf{e}_z \\
  |\dot{\mathbf{s}}(v)| &= 1 \\
  \sqrt{\dot{a}(v)^2+\dot{b}(v)^2} &= 1 \\
  \mathbf{x}(u,v) &= \mathbf{r}(u)+a(v) \mathbf{n}(u)+b(v) \mathbf{e}_z \\
  \partial_u \mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{r}'(u)+a(v) \mathbf{n}'(u) \\
  &= [1-\kappa a(v)] \mathbf{t} \\
   \partial_v \mathbf{x} &= \dot{a}(v) \mathbf{n}+\dot{b}(v) \mathbf{e}_z \\
  \partial_u \mathbf{x} \times \partial_v \mathbf{x} &=
  [1-\kappa a(v)][-\dot{b}(v) \mathbf{n}+\dot{a}(v) \mathbf{e}_z] \\
  \mathbf{N} &=
  \frac{\partial_u \mathbf{x} \times \partial_v \mathbf{x}}
       {|\partial_u \mathbf{x} \times \partial_v \mathbf{x}|} \\
  &= \frac{-\dot{b}(v) \mathbf{n}+\dot{a}(v) \mathbf{e}_z}
          {\sqrt{\dot{a}(v)^2+\dot{b}(v)^2}} \\
  &= -\dot{b}(v) \mathbf{n}+\dot{a}(v) \mathbf{e}_z
\end{align*}